# How do I filter log entries in Logs Explorer by service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I don't see anything to indicate which service account was used to write a log entry in Google Cloud Logging. Additionally, there doesn't seem to be anything indicating where a log entry originated, like a client ID or IP address.

How do I filter log entries by service account or IP address in the Logs Explorer (or elsewhere in the GCP)?

I'm using different service accounts (with authentication using JSON key files) to write log entries using the Python "google-cloud-logging" client library from different Python applications located outside the Google Cloud.

I was expecting that each log entry would include fields for the service account, client ID, and IP address, because it seems like a massive security oversight to not include basic auditing information like this on each log entry.

Comment: Do you require to have logs on the logs? And I don't understand  your use case. Why do you need to know the source that write into the logs? I can understand that you want to know the IP of the user that use your service, but the IP of the service makes no sense!

Comment: No, I just want the log entries to include a field that indicates what service account was used to create the log entry. Each running instance of the Python program can use a different service account (with its own JSON key file) and be located in a different location (IP address).

Comment: To clarify, I think you might be assuming that I'm talking about web services with web clients. I'm not. I'm talking about utilizing GCP logging for centralized logging for distributed python programs running outside GCP.

Comment: Ok, understood. So no, there is not that information. You have to add in the log entry the runtime context to be able to get these information.

Comment: Doesn't it seem like a terrible security flaw to depend on the client to provide this information instead of just using the authentication information readily available from the logging server? I mean, the client can be hacked to pretend that it is using a different service account name and blame someone else for what it is doing. And, unless the client has a public IP address, it won't even know which IP address the request is being routed through without doing some type of public IP address discovery, which may be wrong or change at any time.

Comment: Your use case is very interesting. Open a case to the support to go deeper in that topic. It could interest the engineering team